# Solving a funky differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, electromagnetism

I'm currently trying to solve the DE that defines charge in a circuit containing an Inductor, Capacitor, Resistor and (crucially) a Memristor. This needs to be able to work for any variable values and ends up being of the form:

$$k_1 \cdot y'' + k_2 \cdot y' + k_3 \cdot yy' + k_4 \cdot y = k_5 \cdot \cos(k_6 \cdot x)$$

(Hopefully that works, first time using LaTex)

If someone knows whether or not this is even solvable (or has the solution) that would be great, or even just some guidance on how to approach the $yy'$ term along with dealing with all of the unknown constants would be appreciated as well, as that's not something I've come across before.

I'm hoping this is the right place for this post, if not please do let me know.

Comment: In general, nonlinear ODEs have no closed form solution. If Mathematica/WolframAlpha doesn't give you a solution, you should turn to numerical methods.

Comment: If $k_3 = 0$ then you could easily solve it via using laplace transforms (you can see the solution [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DSolve%5Ba+y%27%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+b+y%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+d+y%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+f+Cos%5Bg+x%5D%2C+y%5Bx%5D%2C+x%5D)). It's trivial that $k_n=0\wedge n\in\mathbb{N}$ is another solution. If $k_n\ne0\wedge n\in\mathbb{N}$ then i would try numerical methods.